# OS X Mavericks: rubygems broken (after some homebrew and rvm mistakes?)

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

(Huge caveat: I'm a very smart developer, and totally knowledgeable at the command-line… but I'm an iOS developer. The mechanicry and interactions between OS X's built-in `ruby`, `gem`, a `homebrew`-installed `ruby`, and what `rvm` does are subtleties I only recently learned. That said…)

I'm trying to get back to a baseline working OS X system `ruby` install. I don't want to use `rvm`, I don't want to use `homebrew` to install a different `ruby`… I just want this one to work.

Here's what doesn't work:

```
% ○ gem help
WARNING:  Unknown command /usr/local/bin. Try gem help commands

% ○ gem help commands
WARNING:  Unknown command /usr/local/bin. Try gem help commands
```

In an attempt to ignore all this noise and move on with my day:

```
% ○ sudo gem install bundler
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '/usr/local/bin' (>= 0) in any repository
[time elapses]
Successfully installed bundler-1.7.3
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.7.3
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

My system configuration:

- System `ruby`:

```
% ○ where ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

% ○ ruby --version                                                       
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

- System `gem`:

```
% ○ where gem
/usr/bin/gem

% ○ gem --version
2.0.14
```

OS X version:

```
% ○ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
BuildVersion:   13F34
```

Previous things I've done that have probably mutated the system:
- Installed `ruby` via `homebrew`. I've since backed that out with `brew uninstall ruby`.
- Installed `rvm` via `rvm`'s homepage instructions. I've since backed that out with `rvm implode`, and by reverting the applicable changes to my `.zsh*` files (which I have under version control).

So… what's going on here? Why is `gem` talking about `/usr/local/bin/`?

Som info about `gem`:

```
% ○ which gem
/usr/bin/gem

% ○ type gem
gem is /usr/bin/gem

% ○ file /usr/bin/gem                                                                 
/usr/bin/gem: a /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby script text executable
```

```
% ○ cat /usr/bin/gem                                                                  
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
#--
# Copyright 2006 by Chad Fowler, Rich Kilmer, Jim Weirich and others.
# All rights reserved.
# See LICENSE.txt for permissions.
#++

require 'rubygems'
require 'rubygems/gem_runner'
require 'rubygems/exceptions'

required_version = Gem::Requirement.new ">= 1.8.7"

unless required_version.satisfied_by? Gem.ruby_version then
  abort "Expected Ruby Version #{required_version}, is #{Gem.ruby_version}"
end

args = ARGV.clone

begin
  Gem::GemRunner.new.run args
rescue Gem::SystemExitException => e
  exit e.exit_code
end
```

Comment: @mpapis thanks but no thanks on that edit.

Comment: one block of text is harder to read, but I have seen it already, so it's ok

Comment: the script looks good, can you add `which gem` and `type gem`

Comment: added. I think this has to do with some strange pathing stuff from `homebrew`. Super weird.

Comment: Cool downvote. Care to leave feedback on why?

Comment: it was your mistake, this question would help much anyone, it's specific to a mistake you did

Comment: I disagree: I ran into this as a part of `homebrew`'s `ruby`. This info will help anyone who installs `ruby` via `homebrew`, then uninstalls it and has issues with `gem` afterwards.

Comment: setting `gem: /usr/local/bin` in `gemrc` has nothing to do with homebrew .. unless it has - but then it's a bug in homebrew

Answer (score 4):

I found it. Dug through a whole bunch of bullshit in `gem`, through `gem_runner.rb` and `command_manager.rb` into `command.rb`, where I found:

```
  # Adds extra args from ~/.gemrc

  def add_extra_args(args)
```

What's in my `.gemrc`? Well, for one, it's not tracked in my git-backed `.dotfiles`. Two:

```
% ○ cat ~/.gemrc                                                                                   --- 
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:benchmark: false
:sources: 
- http://rubygems.org/
- http://gems.github.com
:update_sources: true
gem: /usr/local/bin
:backtrace: false
:verbose: true
```

Note this line: `gem: /usr/local/bin`. That was a modification I made when I got `ruby` installed as part of `homebrew`.

Now this works as expected:

```
% ○ gem help
RubyGems is a sophisticated package manager for Ruby.  This is a
basic help message containing pointers to more information.

  Usage:
    gem -h/--help
    gem -v/--version
[snipped]
```

Comment: you should open bug report for rubygems, the error message was not helpful at all, glad it had nothing to do with rvm :)

Comment: I had your same problem with `gem help`. Fixed it by deleting .gemrc.
I see though that [instructions on homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Gems,-Eggs-and-Perl-Modules.md#with-systems-ruby) are fixed:  
`echo "gem: -n/usr/local/bin" >> ~/.gemrc` note the -n